Postfix+Dovecot+Samba DC+LDAP aliases
I need to set up aliases to redirect one user to another. How to do it?
enter code here


You can setup simple hash tables to redirect mail to another user. For example, consider a table with following contents.
# hash table
a@test.com b@test.com

Adding this to vritual_alias_maps will redirect mails from a -> b
In case of LDAP, we have to configure an LDAP table with correct filters and result attribute. Following table will return uid if the ldap search for mail or mailalternateaddress under the search_base is successful. You would have to return field containing the forwarding address. You would also have to update the query accordingly.
# ldap table
server_host = localhost:389
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
bind_pw = test
search_base = dc=example,dc=com
query_filter = (&(objectClass=qmailUser)(accountStatus=active)(|(mail=%s)(mailAlternateAddress=%s)))
result_attribute = uid

I made a few changes to above filter so that i can route mails to other id's for accounts who can only forward mails
query_filter = (&(objectClass=qmailUser)(deliveryMode=nolocal)(|(mail=%s)(mailAlternateAddress=%s)))
result_attribute = mailForwardingAddress


in paste in main.cf? I have virtual_alias_maps=ldap:/etc/postfix/ad_mail_groups.cf

main.cf should contain virtual_alias_maps. ad_mail_groups.cf should contain ldap table.
The order of files given is important. If multiple tables are configured in virtual_alias_maps, for example users for which mail should be forwarded and regular non forwarding users., i prefer adding forwarding users table first as the forwarding users will be filtered out before postfix checks the next table.
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:forwarding_users_table.cf, ldap:some_group, ldap:regular_table


I create ldap:forwarding_users_table.cf     with new filter.      Where should I insert the required forwarding addresses?
can I contact you?

add it to virtual_alias_maps

i didnt understand about
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:forwarding_users_table.cf, ldap:some_group, ldap:regular_table

Ans:
 virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ad_mail_groups.cf, ldap:/etc/ldap/ldap_table.cf

postfix here will first check ad_mail_groups.cf table. If an attribute is returned by the table, postfix will not check the next ldap_table.cf**. so, in case the group returns an attribute for a user search, it will not check the ldap_table and the mail will be sent to group. hence the order is important.

My /etc/postfix/ad_mail_groups.cf
version = 3
server_host = pve.local:389
search_base = dc=pve,dc=local
timeout = 3
scope = sub
query_filter = (&(mail=%s)(sAMAccountType=268435456))
result_filter = %s
leaf_result_attribute = mail
special_result_attribute = member
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=vmail,cn=users,dc=pve,dc=local
bind_pw = 1!

# ldap table
server_host = pve.local:389
bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=vmail,dc=pve,dc=local
bind_pw = 1!
search_base = dc=pve,dc=local

